# Java 8 - filtering a collection using an external parameter

Tags: casting, java-8, java-stream

I have a map of base class (Animal)  containing concrete successors.
I want to filter and get an array using java stream and each time I write the following full long line of code:
( e.g. filter by concrete Dog class)

```
MyBaseObjectAnimalMap.values().stream().
     filter(x -> x instanceof Dog).
     map(x -> (Dog) x).
     toArray(Dog[]::new);
```

Is there a way to abstract this?

I want to implement a private method with the following signature:

```
filterMapByType(Map<String,Animal> map, Class<T extends Animal> type)
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can supply an `IntFunction` for calling `toArray` so that you get an array of type T instead of an array of objects.

```
public static <T extends Animal> T[] filterMapByType(Map<String, Animal> map, Class<T> type, IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
    return map.values()
              .stream()
              .filter(type::isInstance)
              .map(type::cast)
              .toArray(generator);
}
```

and for an example of call:

```
Dog[] dogs = filterMapByType(map, Dog.class, Dog[]::new);
```

`Dog[]::new` is equivalent to `length -> new Dog[length]`, that is, a function that takes an int as parameter and that returns an array of type `Dog` with the size `length`.

If returning a list is possible then you could use `.collect(toList());` instead of `.toArray(generator);`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is. The only thing you'll have to do differently is using the [Class#isAssignableFrom(Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) method rather than `instanceof`. Oh, and use Reflection to create that Array of course. Check out [Array.html#newInstance(Class, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-) for that.

So, the end result would look something like this (though untested):

```
filterMapByType(Map<String, Animal> map, Class<T extends Animal> type) {
    return map.values().stream().
               filter(animal -> type.isAssignableFrom(animal.getClass())).
               map(type::cast).
               toArray(Array.newInstance(type, map.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can surely externalize the predicate condition and at run time based on predicate condition it can decide which one to filter .

for e.g. I have written a sample program to demonstrate it .

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class AnimalSelector {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Animal> animalList = Arrays.asList(new Dog(),new Horse(),new Human(),new Dog(),new Horse(),new Human());
        Predicate<Animal> dogFilter = x-> x instanceof  Dog;
        System.out.println(toAnimalArray(animalList,dogFilter));

        Predicate<Animal> humanFilter = x-> x instanceof  Human;
        System.out.println(toAnimalArray(animalList,humanFilter));

        Predicate<Animal> horseFilter = x-> x instanceof  Dog;
        System.out.println(toAnimalArray(animalList,horseFilter));


    }

    public static <Animal> List<Animal> toAnimalArray(List<Animal> animalList,Predicate<Animal> filterCondition){
        return animalList.stream()
                .filter(filterCondition)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}

interface Animal{
    public void eat();

}

class Dog implements  Animal{
    private String animalType;
    public Dog( ) {
        this.animalType = "dog";
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog{" +
                "animalType=" + animalType +
                '}';
    }
}

class Human implements  Animal{

    private String animalType;
    public Human( ) {
        this.animalType = "Human";
    }


    @Override
    public void eat() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Human{" +
                "animalType=" + animalType +
                '}';
    }
}

class Horse implements  Animal{
    private String animalType;
    public Horse( ) {
        this.animalType = "Horse";
    }


    @Override
    public void eat() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Horse{" +
                "animalType=" + animalType +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I wrote a small library called [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) which among other things can solve your problem pretty easily:

```
StreamEx.ofValues(MyBaseObjectAnimalMap).select(Dog.class).toArray(Dog[]::new)
```

Also note that it does not add a map step. Instead it uses unsafe cast after filtering, because it's already known that all stream elements are now dogs. Thus the pipeline remains shorter.